# Ternary operator inside a return statement

Tags: c++, c++11, return, expression, ternary-operator

I was writing a recursive function, and encountered a problem at the return statement.

```
int SumOfEvenNumbers(int v[], int i)
{
    if ( i > v[0] )
        return 0;
    return SumOfEvenNumbers(v, i+1) + (v[i]%2==0)?v[i]:0;
}
```

The function is called like this:

```
SumOfEvenNumbers(vector_indexed_from_1, 1);
//v[0] is equal to the number of elements, excluding itself
```

What I expected the ternary if to return was either v[i] or 0 ( in case it is even ) but apparently after printing the result of every ternary if to the screen, the only values that result from the expression are 1 and 0.

```
int SumOfEvenNumbers(int v[], int i)
{
    if ( i > v[0] )
        return 0;
    cout << (v[i]%2==0)?(v[i]):(0); // either a 1 or a 0
    return SumOfEvenNumbers(v, i+1) + (v[i]%2==0)?v[i]:0;
}
```

The way I fixed this is by initializing a variable with the result of the expression and then adding that to the return value.

```
int SumOfEvenNumbers(int v[], int i)
{
    if ( i > v[0] )
        return 0;
    int rv = (v[i]%2==0)?(v[i]):(0);
    return SumOfEvenNumbers(v, i+1) + rv;
}
```

Could anyone explain what is happening? Is it possible to avoid declaring a variable in order to obtain the correct result?

Comment: This is very confusing. Write a simple `main` function that calls `SumOfEvenNumbers` with sample values that show the problem, then explain what output you expect and what you got.

Comment: [MCVE] please.  It should only take another dozen lines to make a complete, compiling set of source code that will actually demonstrate your problem with behaviour you cannot explain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ternary conditional operator has lower precedence than operator+.
Your code was actually parsed as

```
(SumOfEvenNumbers(v, i+1) + (v[i]%2==0)) ? v[i] : 0;
```

To get what you want, use parentheses

```
SumOfEvenNumbers(v, i+1) + ((v[i]%2==0)) ? v[i] : 0);
```

See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Thanks everyone! It didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone explain what is happening?

Take a look at [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Here ternary conditional happens to have very low priority. In `SumOfEvenNumbers(v, i+1) + (v[i]%2==0)?v[i]:0` expression it is calculated **after** `+` given you unexpected result.

> Is it possible to avoid declaring a variable in order to obtain the correct result?

I cases when you are not sure about order of operators it is safe to use brackets `()` to indicate the order explicitly. So `SumOfEvenNumbers(v, i+1) + ((v[i]%2==0)?v[i]:0)` will be calculated as expected.